# A value of type 'Future<List<Questoes>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Questoes>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to read a json from local file and return a list of elements inside, but it's giving this error.

```
Future<List<Questoes>> loadQuestions(String gameCode) async {
  QuestionModel fullQuestions = await getFileContents(gameCode);
  List<Questoes> questoes = fullQuestions.questoes!;
  print(questoes);
  return questoes;
}

List<Questoes> sampledata = loadQuestions('6s3k8');
```

This is where sampledata gets initialized, and it's inside the quiz controller. The function loadQuestions is after the QuestionModel class (json to dart)

```
final List<Questoes> _questions = sampledata;
  List<Questoes> get questions => _questions;
```

I have tried using a .then method but it did not work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The function returns a `Future` which is a promise that it will return the data after loading anything that's there, hence, you've to wait for it to send the data, if you don't wait, what you get is the future/promise. Hence, either use `await` as mentioned in the below answer or use `.then()` after the function as `loadQuestions().then((sampledata) {  //Do something here }`.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong but can figure what. I added the part where sampledata gets initialized.

Comment: `I have tried using a .then method but it did not work.` - How? What's the error?

Comment: A value of type 'Future<Null>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Questoes>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Questoes>'. and the code: List<Questoes> sampledata = loadQuestions('6s3k8').then((List<Questoes> sampledata) {
  print(sampledata);
});

Comment: No, the function .then() doesn't return the value as you've tried to use it. Just use this
`List<Questoes> sampledata = []; //New line here

loadQuestions('6s3k8').then((data) => sampledata = data);`

Answer (score 1):

Add an await

```
List<Questoes> sampledata = await loadQuestions('6s3k8');
```

Comment: It says "The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'." even though it already is async

Comment: @MarcoTúlioBarros If it still says that, then it means the line where you call the function `loadQuestions` might be in another child function, for example `setState` and you've to mark that function `async`.

Comment: Yeah if you add an await mark the method as asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

As `loadQuestions` is `async`, one needs to add an `await` when calling it.

Also, if using `await`, it has to be placed inside a method using `async` itself.

```dart
Future<void> bla() async {
  List<Questoes> sampledata = await loadQuestions('6s3k8');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.